# Form focus jQuery shorten code

Tags: jquery, forms, focus

I have only limited knowledge about JS and jQuery and I don't know how to change this code.

```
$('.form input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
$('.form input').on('focusout', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

Is it possible to shorten this code? If yes. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly fine as is. You can chain the `on` calls, though:

```
$('.form input')
  .on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  })
  .on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  });
```

---

Side note: Normally you'd use `focusin`/`focusout` or `focus/blur` rather than mix-and-match.

Comment: Thx for note, if don't know this)

Answer (score 0):

Using `focus` and `blur` .

```js
$("#txtTest").focus(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #623886;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id='txtTest' />

</div>
```